# Python .remove issue

Tags: python, list, element, remove-method

Is this a bug of Python?
I define a simple list:
`a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`
I copy this list into another variable `z`:
`z = a`
I remove one element from the first list:
`a.remove('a')` which produces `['b', 'c', 'd']` as expected.
But then ask Python to display `z` too. The output is: `['b', 'c', 'd']` as well!? As if `a` and `z` are pointing to the same value, instead of being separate variables?

Comment: "Is this a bug of Python?" - 99.999999999999999999999999999% chance, no.

Comment: And on reading past that sentence, I see that your confusion stems from the belief that `z = a` makes a separate copy of a `list`. It does not. See the linked duplicate, and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) for more.

Comment: You create a shallow copy. Meaning both your variables are aliases for the same list. To create a deep copy (both aliases point to their own list) you can use the 'copy.deepcopy()' from the 'copy' module.

Comment: @deloz - a shallow copy would be `z = a[:]` or `z = list(a)`. This is simply asigning a second name to the same list, no copying involved.

Comment: Thank you... using `z = list(a)` solves that. Creating a "deep copy".